# Google Search Appliance isn't displaying document's title

Tags: google-search-appliance

For some reason, our Google Search Appliance isn't displaying the title of some of our larger files (even though they have a title property).  Instead, it's showing the filepath.  For example, it does this for 3 word documents that are about 4mb, but it doesn't do it for a powerpoint file that is around 5mb.  Any idea what causes this and if there is a workaround to get the title to display?

Answer (score 0):

The GSA will fetch a title based on meta, or the title it can find in the document. If it cannot find a suitable title tag it will use the filepath. Suitability could be length, format, character encoding, position, etc.

This used to be well documented, but I am struggling to find it now apart from vague mentions here https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/4411411?hl=en

Also, as a less important check make sure file sizes are not being exceeded as per the configuration. https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/4411411?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can read about how GSA determines the title of documents [here](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/file_formats/file_formats.html#1072831).
I don't think file size matters here unless you have specified very less value for Crawl and Index > Index Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the "&getfields=title" query string in your search call. To just get all fields in  tags, you can just set the query string to "&getfields=*".